# mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given :(

Tags: php, mysqli

when i run the code it shows this error . "mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given"

```
<?php

function confirm_query($result_set) {
if (!$reslt_set) {
    die("database query failed");
}
}

function find_all_subjects() {
global $connection;
$query = "SELECT * ";
$query .= "FROM subjects ";
$query .= "WHERE visible=1 ";
$query .= "ORDER BY position ASC ";
$subject_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
confirm_query($subject_set);
return $subject_set;
}
?>
```

Comment: my db_connetion is mysqli_ :( ... this is the code     <?php
$db_host="localhost";
$db_user="root";
$db_pass="";
$db_name="cycle_world";
$connection= mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_name);

if(mysqli_connect_errno($connection)){
 die("Database connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error()."(".mysqli_connect_errno().")");
}
?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's your complete file then `$connection` is going to be empty (null), you're not creating the connection anywhere.

You may be creating the connection in another file, hence `global $connection;` but then you'd need to include this file to get the connection.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `mysql_` and `mysqli` functions. This might be your problem. You can't do mixing of mysqli and mysql functions together in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* Create table doesn't return a resultset */
if (mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myCity LIKE City") === TRUE) {
    printf("Table myCity successfully created.\n");
}

/* Select queries return a resultset */
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT Name FROM City LIMIT 10")) {
    printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", mysqli_num_rows($result));

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

Got this from php.net only